# What's an idiomatic way to delete a value from HashMap if it is empty?

Tags: rust

The following code works, but it doesn't look nice as the definition of `is_empty` is too far away from the usage.

```
fn remove(&mut self, index: I, primary_key: &Rc<K>) {
    let is_empty;
    {
        let ks = self.data.get_mut(&index).unwrap();
        ks.remove(primary_key);
        is_empty = ks.is_empty();
    }
    // I have to wrap `ks` in an inner scope so that we can borrow `data` mutably.
    if is_empty {
        self.data.remove(&index);
    }
}
```

Do we have some ways to drop the variables in condition before entering the if branches, e.g.

```
if {ks.is_empty()} {
    self.data.remove(&index);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever you have a double look-up of a key, you need to think [**Entry API**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry).

With the entry API, you get a handle to a key-value pair and can:

- read the key,
- read/modify the value,
- remove the entry entirely (getting the key and value back).

It's extremely powerful.

In this case:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;

fn remove(hm: &mut HashMap<i32, String>, index: i32) {
    if let Entry::Occupied(o) = hm.entry(index) {
        if o.get().is_empty() {
            o.remove_entry();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut hm = HashMap::new();
    hm.insert(1, String::from(""));

    remove(&mut hm, 1);

    println!("{:?}", hm);
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use Entry API but struggled for my use case, which is to modify the value first, and then, if after modification, the value turns out to satisfy certain criteria/becomes empty, delete it from the hashmap. Is that not feasible with this approach?

Comment: @xij: It's very close to what Shepmaster's answer, below, is doing. Just be careful with the scope of your borrows, that is, enclose the modification inside a block `{ let key = occupied.get_mut(); /* mutate */ }` and then check/remove.

Comment: Trying to give credit where credit is due, the answer below was the OP's, they just put it in the *question*. They chose not to move it to an answer themselves, so [I did it for them](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43892402/3) (this is why it's community wiki).

Answer (score 6):

I did this in the end:

```
match self.data.entry(index) {
    Occupied(mut occupied) => {
        let is_empty = {
            let ks = occupied.get_mut();
            ks.remove(primary_key);
            ks.is_empty()
        };
        if is_empty {
            occupied.remove();
        }

    },
    Vacant(_) => unreachable!()
}
```

Comment: This method suits my use case of first modifying the value, and then determining whether to remove it or not. The accepted answer didn't seem to be able to do this.

Comment: Why did you make this community wiki? You still deserve the reputation for answering your own questions.

Comment: @MattJoiner the OP did not post this, I did. Unfortunately, the OP [answered their own question *in the question*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43892402/revisions), so I moved it to an answer so that it could be voted up and down separately. It wouldn’t make sense for me to get rep for it, so community wiki it is. This is also [mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892402/whats-an-idiomatic-way-to-delete-a-value-from-hashmap-if-it-is-empty/43990739?noredirect=1#comment97227870_43892581).